# Regex skipping matches

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to select multiple matches in a string that looks like:

> 123
>   blah
>   END
>   45
>   blah
>   END

Ideally I would like it to return 2 matches of starting with the digit sequence and ending with the END string. I am using the following:

```
Regex splitter = new Regex(@"^\d{2,3}(.*)END", RegexOptions.Singleline);
foreach (Match res in splitter.Matches(content))
{
   Console.WriteLine(res.ToString());
}
```

However the above pattern is returning the entire input string in one match. I have a feeling it is something to do with the 'Singleline' option. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the `*` quantifier to lazy form (with `(.*?)` syntax). At the moment it attempts to match as *many* symbols in the string as possible - and succeeds in doing that, of course, as you have several blocks ending with `END`.

With `?` added, the engine will attempt to match the pattern with as *few* symbols as possible, finishing `(.*?)` match right before the first END it encounters.

Comment: ahh! thanks so much, I had a feeling it would be something silly.